# "Stack around the variable 'b' was corrupted." (No heap allocations)

Tags: c++, matrix

So I have a simple matrix class, and when I log it to the console everything is fine, but the problem occurs when the program terminates.

I haven't allocated any heap memory, it's just a simple template class that can log a matrix to the console. (I plan on adding addition, subtraction, and multiplication though.)

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using std::cout, std::cin, std::ostream;

template<typename T = float, int R = 4, int C = R>
class Matrix {
public:
    Matrix(T identity = T{}) {
        for (int i = 0; i < R; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < C; ++j)
                matrix[i][j] = T{};

        for (int i = 0; i < R; ++i)
            matrix[i][i] = identity;
    }

    T& operator()(int row, int column = 0) {
        if (C == 1)
            return matrix[(row < R&& row > -1 ? row : 0)][0];
        else
            return matrix[(row < R&& row > -1 ? row : 0)][(column < R&& column > -1 ? column : 0)];
    }

    const T& operator()(int row, int column = 0) const {
        if (C == 1)
            return matrix[(row < R&& row > -1 ? row : 0)][0];
        else
            return matrix[(row < R&& row > -1 ? row : 0)][(column < R&& column > -1 ? column : 0)];
    }

    T* ToArray() {
        return reinterpret_cast<T*>(matrix);
    }

    const T* ToArray() const {
        return reinterpret_cast<const T* const>(matrix);
    }
private:
    T matrix[R][C];
};

template<typename T, int R = 4, int C = 0>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, const Matrix<T, R, C>& matrix) {

    const T* matrixArray = matrix.ToArray();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < R; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < C; ++j) {
            stream << (j == 0 ? '[' : ' ');
            stream << matrix(i, j);
            stream << (j == C - 1 ? ']' : ' ');
        }
        stream << (i == R - 1 ? '\0' : '\n');
    }

    return stream;
}

int main() {

    Matrix a(1.0f);
    Matrix<float, 4, 1> b(1.0f);

    cout << a << '\n';
    // no error occurs when I do this
    //cout << b(1, 0) << '\n';
    cout << b << '\n';

    /* OUTPUT
    [1  0  0  0]
    [0  1  0  0]
    [0  0  1  0]
    [0  0  0  1]
    [1]
    [0]
    [1]
    [0]
    */

    cin.get();
    // when the error occurs
}
```

Comment: `matrix[i][i] = identity;` What if the matrix is *not* square?

Comment: @dxiv A 4 x 1 matrix gives me this output.
/*
[1  0  0  0]
[0  1  0  0]
[0  0  1  0]
[0  0  0  1]
[1]
[0]
[1]
[0]
*/


Looks fine to me.

Comment: `column < R&& column > -1 ? column : 0)` it should be `column < C`

Comment: @xKaihatsu A 4x1 matrix has no element `matrix[1][1]` but the code writes to it regardless. That's a buffer overrun.

Comment: @dxiv good catch, I will put that into answer if you do not mind

Comment: @Slava No worries at all. That was just a hint, yours is an answer proper.

Comment: Typo.   Both `operator()`s have a return statements of the form `return matrix[(row < R&& row > -1 ? row : 0)][(column < R&& column > -1 ? column : 0)];`   In this,  `column` should be compared with `C`, not `R` - and the result of the error is potentially accessing outside array bounds.      (Unrelated, since you are enforcing non-negative indices, why not using an `unsigned` type instead of `int`?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue is this loop (thanks to **dxiv** )

```
    for (int i = 0; i < R; ++i)
        matrix[i][i] = identity;
```

access array out of bounds when R > C, you should eliminate that loop and modify previous to (assuming logic to always fill diagonal with identity in your code is correct):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < R; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < C; ++j)
            matrix[i][j] = i == j ? identity : T{};
```

also in this code:

```
 return matrix[(row < R&& row > -1 ? row : 0)][(column < R&& column > -1 ? column : 0)];
```

you compare `column` with `R` but you should compare with `C` and looks like that's the reason you handle case `C==1` separately. Just fix this and you do not need that condition anymore.

Note: I do not see usage of methods when you `reinterpret_cast` your array to a pointer, but most probably you are doing something wrong here.